# Mongodb: find records that repeat each day during a week

Tags: mongodb

I need to find only that records that repeat every day during a week (from one date to second date). How can I do it in mongodb?

Thank you for help.

Сollection like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("585c904b7e255dc664179091"),
"tWhen" : NumberLong("1482461259892"),
"opMode" : 2,
```

}

I need to find only those records that are repeated every day for a specific week.

Comment: Share your code how much you have tried.better for getting the help faster. @Arto Rovie

Comment: just collection like this:

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("585c904b7e255dc664179091"),
 "tWhen" : NumberLong("1482461259892"),
 "opMode" : 2,
}

I need to find only those records that are repeated every day for a specific week.